# Can not load FragmentActivity, google maps v 2

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to display googlemaps v2, on my Android phone LG-E400, with Android OS v 2.3.6.
But I get errors. I searched for similar problems, but there was no suggestions helped me.

Here is my code:

**//MainActivity.java**

```
import com.example.googlemaps2.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       try{
       setContentView(R.layout.main); 

       SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

       GoogleMap map = mf.getMap();
       } catch(Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(this,""+e.getMessage(),5000).show();
       }
   }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemaps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission 
      android:name="com.example.googlemaps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name=
            "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name=
            "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps2.MainActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBK_DUfmBFEae7F_O8xxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**when I run it, log cat shows me those errors, and the programm is crushed.**

```
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps2/com.example.googlemaps2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at loh.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lol.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lzr.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lxn.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lxm.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at fnb.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1631)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     ... 11 more
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps2/com.example.googlemaps2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at loh.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lol.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lzr.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lxn.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at lxm.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at fnb.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1631)
07-01 10:58:16.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5162):     ... 11 more
```

**Can some one help me with that?**

Comment: plz check your Google play services lib properly configure or not........

Comment: these maybe useful: http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part6

Comment: Thank you for response:=) But how to know wether play services configured properly or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had a look at console, I mentioned that installation of apk always fails,due to incorresponding API level in manifest, because of that it automatically runs, old apk, installed yesterday. Then, when I removed all old apks from mobile phone, and wrote suitable apk version in manifest, it showed me the map.